# how Bitcoin Benefits from giving u s currency(other then money from ads)

Tags: mining-reward

Now, I have a pretty simple question to ask , How does Bitcoin benefit from giving us money for solving math problems? Another question is that why does it want us to do it? & is there a bigger purpose behind it???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Who are you solving algorithms for and why?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/30109/who-are-you-solving-algorithms-for-and-why)

Comment: Also: [What value does mining provide?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/37416/what-value-does-mining-provide?rq=1)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because too broad. Next to the two links, you may also look at bitcoin.org, and understand the design goals of bitcoin (censorship resistant payment network ...)

Answer (score 1):

"Bitcoin" is not a company. Bitcoin is an open-source project and a lot of people are working on it. And an open-source project does not need to get rich. The intention of a big part of that community is more like "changing something".

> How does Bitcoin benefit from giving us money for solving math problems?

You did probably not understand that "solving the sha256-algorithm (that's what solving math problems means)" secures the network by preventing [double-spends](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4974/what-is-a-double-spend).